# PHP RSS getting weird characters

Tags: php, laravel, rss

I have this code:

```
$curl = new CurlX();
$curl->setFollowRedirects();
$curl->setXmlDecoder(null);
$curl->setHeader('Accept','application/atom+xml, application/rss+xml, application/rdf+xml;q=0.9, application/xml;q=0.8, text/xml;q=0.8, text/html;q=0.7, unknown/unknown;q=0.1, application/unknown;q=0.1, */*;q=0.1');
$curl->setHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11');
$curl->getAndClose($url);

return trim($curl->rawResponse);
```

I noticed that I am getting these weird character results:

[image]

Another weird thing is that this is only happening on my live server, but in my local, I don't get those weird characters.

These are the headers that I send when getting that RSS Feed:

```
Curl\CaseInsensitiveArray^ {#2499
  -data: array:5 [
    "request-line" => "GET /feed/ HTTP/2"
    "host" => "example.com"
    "user-agent" => "PHP-Curl-Class/4.13.0 (+https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) PHP/7.4.0 curl/7.67.0"
    "connection" => "Close"
    "accept" => "application/atom+xml, application/rss+xml, application/rdf+xml;q=0.9, application/xml;q=0.8, text/xml;q=0.8, text/html;q=0.7, unknown/unknown;q=0.1, application/unknown;q=0.1, */*;q=0.1"
  ]
  -keys: array:5 [
    "request-line" => "Request-Line"
    "host" => "Host"
    "user-agent" => "user-agent"
    "connection" => "connection"
    "accept" => "accept"
  ]
}
```

These are the response headers that I get from them:

```
Curl\CaseInsensitiveArray^ {#2498
  -data: array:19 [
    "status-line" => "HTTP/2 200 "
    "server" => "nginx"
    "date" => "Fri, 23 Jul 2021 07:08:35 GMT"
    "content-type" => "application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8"
    "content-length" => "18498"
    "x-sucuri-id" => "18013"
    "x-xss-protection" => "1; mode=block"
    "x-frame-options" => "SAMEORIGIN"
    "x-content-type-options" => "nosniff"
    "content-security-policy" => "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
    "vary" => "Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding"
    "last-modified" => "Tue, 20 Jul 2021 18:01:59 GMT"
    "link" => "<https://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/""
    "x-cacheable" => "CacheAlways: feed"
    "cache-control" => "max-age=600, must-revalidate"
    "etag" => "W/"cad26acdf674110a0745d208fe822a60-gzip""
    "x-cache" => "HIT: 1"
    "x-sucuri-cache" => "HIT"
    "accept-ranges" => "bytes"
  ]
  -keys: array:19 [
    "status-line" => "Status-Line"
    "server" => "server"
    "date" => "date"
    "content-type" => "content-type"
    "content-length" => "content-length"
    "x-sucuri-id" => "x-sucuri-id"
    "x-xss-protection" => "x-xss-protection"
    "x-frame-options" => "x-frame-options"
    "x-content-type-options" => "x-content-type-options"
    "content-security-policy" => "content-security-policy"
    "vary" => "vary"
    "last-modified" => "last-modified"
    "link" => "link"
    "x-cacheable" => "x-cacheable"
    "cache-control" => "cache-control"
    "etag" => "etag"
    "x-cache" => "x-cache"
    "x-sucuri-cache" => "x-sucuri-cache"
    "accept-ranges" => "accept-ranges"
  ]
}
```

Any tip on this? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Share the final headers (all of them) you get when consuming that please...

Comment: @matiaslauriti i've updated the question with those headers that you mentioned. Thank you very much!